# Serializing Decimal128 to JSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for creating an api where I retrieve values from mongodb. The problem I am facing is that `Decimal128` fields are serialized like:

```
"userid": {
  "high": 3476778912330022912,
  "low": 10776,
  "naN": false,
  "infinite": false,
  "finite": true,
  "negative": false
}
```

Here is the body of my controller:

```
var wrappers = new EmbeddedWrappers(false);

var collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("blah");

var result = collection.find().limit(1000).into(new ArrayList<>());

if (result == null) {
  return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}

return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources<>(Arrays.asList(wrappers.wrap(result))));
```

Any ideas how I can correctly serialize `Decimal128` values so that I only have the value itself?

Comment: You can write a [Custom Serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {

  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    var module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Decimal128.class, new Decimal128Serializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
  }

  private static class Decimal128Serializer extends JsonSerializer<Decimal128> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Decimal128 v, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider p) throws IOException {
      g.writeNumber(v.bigDecimalValue());
    }
  }
}
```